# Validar formulario html

Tags: javascript, html

Deseo validar un formulario `html` con `javascript`pero no me esta funcionando el código es el siguiente:

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/ValidarFormulario/validar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" name="formulario" method="GET" onsubmit="return validarFormulario();">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nombre">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="hombre" value="Hombre"> Hombre
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="mujer" value="Mujer"> Mujer
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos"> Terminos y Condiciones
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function validarFormulario() {
var formulario = document.getElementByName('formulario')[0],
    elementos = formulario.elements,
    boton = document.getElementById('btn');

var validarNombre = function() {
    if (formulario.nombre.value == 0) {
        alert("Completa el campo nombre");
    }
};

var validar = function() {
    validarNombre();
};
formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, debes cancelar el comportamiento por defecto del input submit:

- event.preventDefault();
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Por otro lado, la función, getElementByName no existe, getElement**s**ByName si:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Te copio el código corregido:

Validar.js

```
function validarFormulario() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formulario = document.getElementsByName('formulario')[0],
    elementos = formulario.elements,
    boton = document.getElementById('btn');

    var validarNombre = function() {
    if (formulario.nombre.value == 0) { -> COMPROBACIONES.
        alert("Completa el campo nombre");
    }
};

var validar = function() {
    validarNombre();
};
formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);
}
```

--- SOLUCIÓN TRAS COMENTARIOS ---

Debido a que ya tienes en la etiqueta form la acción "Onsubmit", te bastaría con el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="validar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" name="formulario" method="GET" onsubmit="validarFormulario()">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nombre">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="hombre" value="Hombre"> Hombre
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="mujer" value="Mujer"> Mujer
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos"> Terminos y Condiciones
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Y el JS:

```
function validarFormulario() {
    event.preventDefault(); -> Cancelamos el evento del submit.
    var formulario = document.getElementsByName('formulario')[0],
    elementos = formulario.elements,
    boton = document.getElementById('btn');

    if (formulario.nombre.value == 0) {
        alert("Completa el campo nombre");
    }
    else{
        alert("Nombre : " + formulario.nombre.value);
        event.currentTarget.submit();-> Reanudamos el evento del submit.
    }
};
```

Comment: Si nos metemos dentro del código, haría mas modificaciones, pero ya eso es parte de su aprendizaje. De momento, con la solución planteada, se ejecuta el evento y puede hacer trazas de su código.

Comment: Así es es código de aprendizaje que sigo de un tutorial, lo que pasa es que el código js estaba dentro del html y lo separe, @Zito_MA cuando preciono el boton enviar enviar sale el mensaje una vez y es lo normal pero si vuelvo a precionar sale dos veces a que se debe?

Comment: Se debe, a que el "addEventListener" se ejecuta dentro de la función validarFormulario(), la cual se ejecuta cada vez que se hace submit. Edito la respuesta y te dejo un poco mas claro el código.

Answer (score 1):

A parte de lo que ya te respondieron (y que es correcto), considero prudente proponerte lo siguiente:

- Recupera los elementos y asignalos a variables
- Considera crear una sola función que administre por dentro:

  - El evento `click` al botón del menú
  - Dentro de la función del *handler* revisar con un condicional si el valor de la variable que lee el nombre es igual a "" entonces notifiquemos al usuario que falta su nombre, en caso contrario envía el formulario
- Así también podemos pasar el llamado a la función dentro del script y no invador el HTML
- Es la propiedad value la que deberías revisar para comprobar si el usuario ha escrito o no

```html
        <form action="" name="formulario" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nombre">
            <br>
            <input type="radio" class="sexo" name="sexo" id="hombre" value="Hombre"> Hombre
            <input type="radio" class="sexo" name="sexo" id="mujer" value="Mujer"> Mujer
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos"> Terminos y Condiciones
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="Enviar">
        </form>
      <script>
        let cajaTexto    = document.getElementById("nombre")
        let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".sexo")
        let terminos     = document.getElementById("terminos")
        let botonEnvia   = document.getElementById("btn") 
        
        function validaFormulario () {
          botonEnvia.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
            evento.preventDefault()
            if (cajaTexto.value === "") {
              console.log("Falta tu nombre")
            } else {
              console.log("Formulario enviado")
            }
          })
        }
        
        validaFormulario()
      </script>
```

Comment: Si separo ese código en un archivo js ¿como llamas a la función? desde el html, como invocas el método.

Comment: el código como lo he puesto quedaría igual solo que por separado, ahora para llamarlo en tu HTML deberías hacerlo a través de una etiqueta `script` así: **`<script src="ruta/del/archivo.js"></script>`**

Comment: Entiendo, pero por que objeto ó evento se valida el form usando el js?

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que en esta respuesta yo recupero de forma indivisual cada elemento del mismo, creo una función donde por dentro ejecuto el evento click del botón, prevengo el submit del mismo y con base al uso de condicionales valido si cada uno de estos elementos tiene algún valor ingresado o no, aquí solo lo dejé a nivel del input pero se puede ampliar a todos y cuando estén llenos o chequed entonces se considera un formulario lleno y se procesa

Comment: Separe el código pero no funciona como lo supuse, creare otro hilo.